# ZoomScale of a UIWebView won't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to zoom out by changing the zoomScale of my `UIWebview`. I'm trying to make all the content of the page smaller. Here is my method:

```
-(void)makeSmaller
{
        _mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
        _mainWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.2;
        NSLog(@"zoomScale: %f",_mainWebView.scrollView.zoomScale); //Always 1.000
}
```

the `zoomScale` will always show 1.000 after the `UIWebView` is loaded.

if I set it in here:

```
-(void)loadCurrentMsg
{
    CTCoreMessage *msg = [_messages objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *body = [msg htmlBody];

    [_mainWebView loadHTMLString:body baseURL:nil];
    _mainWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = 0.2;
}
```

The `zoomScale` does change and loads the `UIWebView` smaller but returns to 1.000 when I load the next msg . I thought maybe it got something to do about reloading the page like when you need to reload data in a `UITableView` but inside `makeSmaller` the scale always stays on 1.000 so I don't think refreshing got anything to do with it.

Anyone can tell me what's the difference ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you set `scalesPageToFit` to `NO`?